# Why does this coden tell me lineno1 doesnt exist?

Tags: python

My code is trying to delete the oldest score in a text file when the number of scores is bigger than three. This is the text file:

```
humzah:0:6:5
ikrah:8:6:4
```

This is my code:

```
if userclass=="1": #if userclass is equal to 1
   with open ("Class1scores.txt", "r") as dataforclass1:#open the class 1 file as
#data for class 1 in read plus mode 
        lines = dataforclass1.read().splitlines() #lines is equal to each line on
        #the file (list).
        for lineno1, line in enumerate(lines): #for the line number
            usertaken=input("Have you taken this quiz before, yes or no") #first ask if the user
            #has done this quiz before
            while True: #this states that while it is true
                      if usertaken=="yes": #if the user says yes continue the script
                         break
                      if usertaken=="no": #if the user says no continue the script
                         break
                      else:
                           print("That is not a valid answer! yes or no")#if the user
                           continue
            if usertaken=="yes": #if they have then find the line and add to it
               if line.startswith(username): 
                  print("was found on line", lineno1) #tells the user what lines their name is on
                  lines[lineno1] += ":" + str(score)
                  break
            else:
                lines.append(username + ":" + str(score)) #if they have not add to
                #a new line
                break
   data = "\n".join(lines) + "\n" #data is the list plus indents (\n means new
  #line)
   with open("Class1scores.txt", "w") as file: #opens the file in write mode
        file.write(data) #this writes in to the file
        print(data)

with open('Class1scores.txt','r') as class1file:#with the text file
#as class1file
    lines = []#this creates an empty list
    for x, line in enumerate(class1file):#to find x read the lines
        if lineno1==x:
          class1_list = line.split(':')#split the text file by :
        if len(class1_list) > 4:#if theres more than 4 values
           del class1_list[1]#delete the first score
           line = ':'.join(class1_list)#the line is equal to the
           #data with : as the seperator
        lines.append(line)#append this to the list
    with open("Class1scores.txt",'w') as writefile:
        writefile.write(''.join(lines))
```

For class 1 it just loops the question "have you taken this quiz before" and for the other classes , with the same code copied and pasted, it states "lineno1 is not defined". Any help?

Answer (score 0):

lineno1 is only defined in the if-block where userclass equals 1. In all other cases the variable is never defined and therefore the error is thrown.
If you define lineno1 in the first line of your code, it will be overwritten in the first if-block but you can also use in the 2nd if-block.